# Tangent formula

Tags: math, matrix, trigonometry

I have this formula

```
B = tan(atan(A) + C)
```

where A is the input, B is output and C is a constant. The problem is that sin, cos and tan functions are computationally expensive and also there is quite a big loss of precision along the formula when calculated as 4 byte floats. I am in the process of optimizing my code so is there any way to avoid using these functions even if the total number of calculations is several times higher?

Further background: the numbers A, B and C are the ratio's of x/y coordinate for 3 points on a 2 dimensional plane

Comment: Your formula seems to add an angle (`atan(A)`) to a ratio (`C`).  Based on the rest of your question I can't see how that is a sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll presume that your formula is correct. Mark's comment essentially comes down to the idea that C must have units of an angle for the formula to make sense, but if C is a ratio, then it won't have the proper units. Mark has a valid question.

In the end, you will still need to compute a tangent, but there are things you can do to help a bit.

First, apply a simple trig identity, for the [tangent of a sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). This, combined with the fact that tan(atan(A)) = A, reduces your formula to

```
B = (A + tan(C))/(1 - A*tan(C))
```

Thus you still need to compute ONE tangent, that of C. (Thus precompute tan(C), once.) Nothing will get you around that.

However, there are ways to compute a tangent more efficiently than as a ratio sin(C)/cos(C). For example, a direct series approximation might be better. Or there is a trick using a series for the versine, which is itself more efficient to compute than the tangent series. And for small angles it can be rapidly convergent. You can assure small angles using range reduction tricks for that versine. Other tricks exist too.

Comment: The unit of C is whatever unit the tangent function uses (so degrees in windows calculator, radians in c++). Either way that works

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%5Barctan%5BA%5D%2bC%5D), `tan(atan(A)+C)` can be written as `(A+tan(C))/(1-A*tan(C))`.

You can easily derive this by hand from the tangent sum formula:

> tan(a + b) = (tan a + tan b)/(1 - tan a tan b).

If the implementation of `tan` in your math library is slow or inaccurate it's possible that faster or more precise implementations exist.

Comment: I'm using the standard c++ math library, after going through the function twice i lose around 4 digits of precision and i cant afford doubles :|

Comment: 4 decimal digits? That sounds too much. Could you post an example of the code where you use the formula and the values that you use? Btw the math library used by C++ depends on the compiler and operating system you use.

Answer (score 0):

`atan(A) = atan(x_a/y_a)` for some point is the angle between vector `(x_a,y_a)` and Oy. Because C is a constant, you can precompute some vector `c=(x_c,y_c)` with unit length and inclined to Oy with angle C. Then cos(atan(A)+C) can be expressed as inner product of these vectors divided by length of a. From cos you can get tan using main identity. In the end a got:

```
B = sqrt((x_a^2 + y_a^2)/(x_a*x_c + y_a*y_c)^2 - 1)
```

This might be more effective. Be careful with signs.